# change shared folder permissions

Tags: c#

I've a shared folder on another PC within our network (no credentials are required) and I'm trying to change permissions of this folder from my application.

I'm using this function which works perfectly fine on local folders

```
DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\Username-PC\shared\test");
    //Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\Username-PC\shared\test\newfolder");

    DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
    string User = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User,
                                          FileSystemRights.Delete, AccessControlType.Deny));
    myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User,
                                          FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories, AccessControlType.Deny));
    myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);

    Label3.Text = "Permissions changed!";
```

I can access the shared folder (if i tried creating a directory on it the directory is created successfully) ,,,, but the permissions are not applied!

What am I missing here ?!!

Comment: Is this in a network domain environment, or are you just using ad-hoc networking?

Comment: it's a network domain .... but would be the difference if it was ad-hoc ?!

Answer (score 0):

First Check the SHARE permission of the shared folder (NOT the NFTS permission of the shared "starting" folder !)

There are only three permissions: read, change, full control. To be able to change NTFS folder permissions beneath, the share which you use to access the folder needs full control for your account or a group you are member of (or else admin rights on the remote machine)

Second check the NTFS permission of the folder you want to change: you also need full control or "Change permission" permission to be able to add or remove ACEs (access control entries).

OR

if you are the owner of the directory (you itself created if) you got implicit "P" permissions and can change the ACL even if you don't have "change permission" in the ACL. (but you still need full control on the SHARE)

> > I can access the shared folder (if i tried creating a directory on it the directory is created successfully)

For this it is sufficient having change permissions.